# how to add a random string between filename and file extension in JavaScript in one line?

Tags: javascript, join, split, splice

I want to add a hashstring to file name, so I'm trying to rename the string.

This is what I have:

```
var x = "puh.jpg";
var y = x.split(".");
y.splice(1,0,"foo");
var z = y.join(".");
console.log(z)
```

Which correctly returns: `puh.foo.jpg`.

**Question:**
Can this be done in a single line and without having to declare helper variables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with a regex pretty easily (modulo the complexity of names you need to work with):

```
var y = x.replace(/^([^.]*)\.(.*)$/, '$1.foo.$2');
```

In the regular expression, I've used `( )` to create **groups** (2 of them).  The first group matches all the characters in the name *except* for periods, up to the `.` separating the name from the file extension. (If the extension might not be present at all, then it would look like `^([^.]*)\.?(.*)$` instead, to make the "." optional.)  The second group gets the rest of the name (the extension).

In the replacement string, the constructs "$1" and "$2" are expanded to be the parts of the original string matched by the two groups.

Comment: looks nice. Foo will be an MD5 hash, but the rest... will be filename and extension. Trying.

Comment: @Pointy if possible can you break it down a little  and explain a little please ?

Comment: @SachinG yes sorry, the Internet and I were temporarily separated :-)

Comment: @Pointy, when the extension is missing, your current regular expression variation, `^([^.]*)\.?(.*)$`, will not yield the expected result when replaced with `'$1.foo.$2'`. It will instead yield a trailing dot (as in `puh => puh.foo.`). See my answer below for a correct regular expression that works when there is no extension. It can be easily adjusted to look more like yours, where you reference both the "before the extension" and the "after the extension" parts of the file name with you regular expression. Your regex also fails when there are multiple dots in the file name.

Comment: @MihaiDanila yes, clearly my example won't work when the extension is missing. The original question inherently implied that that wouldn't be the case, but a more general solution is welcome :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use this one. It guarantees that the string is injected at the last dot of the file name. It also works if there is no extension.

```
alert(x.replace(/(\.[^\.]*)?$/, '.foo$1'))
```

Try it with:

```
puh.jpg (=> puh.foo.jpg)
puh.bar.jpg (=> puh.bar.foo.jpg)
foo_bar (=> foo_bar.foo)
foo_bar. (=> foo_bar.foo.)
```

To explain:

- `\.` matches a dot
- `[^\.]` matches any character other than the dot
- `\.[^\.]*` matches a dot followed by zero or more non-dot characters
- `\.[^\.]*$` matches a dot followed by zero or more non-dot characters at the end of the string
- `(\.[^\.]*)$` matches a dot followed by zero or more non-dot characters at the end and allows
  the dot and the characters to be referred to as a group with `$1`
- `'.foo$1'` replaces the matched characters with `.foo` followed by the characters themselves

http://jsfiddle.net/HALf6/

Answer (score 1):

```
x.replace(/\.([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$/, '.foo.$1')
```